Can we have a Genetics and/or Recognition and lobe tag
Can we have a genetics tag?
There are many conditions discussed, questions asked about the genetics and the implications of genetics.
What do people think of a genetics tag? 

Separately:
What about a recognition tag?  

What about lobe/brain tags? 
Temporal, parietal, motor cortex, occipital? 
I think the lobe tags would be good. Grouping very like questions.

genetics?


You'll see what I'm up to in a minute :)

Nah, the question doesn't have to be a wiki :)  I just figured this was easier for people to vote.

LOL, now I can't vote on them :(  Hehe.  I think the anatomical tags are warranted (see my caveat below, though) and I think we do have a lot on genetics.  I'm not sure which need "recognition", though.

Euh .. this tag exists it seems?

What Steven said.

Steven said @what?

lol Are you pulling my leg, Steven, or are you unfamiliar with that phrase?

recognition? 

"object recognition", maybe, would be more general?

Isn't that part of perception? As I learned it perception involves the whole process from sensory input to automatic preselection to retrieval of related information (what you call recognition) to affect and cognition causes by the input to storing the new info (or forgetting it). In a more narrow sense, perception is recognition (or better: the processing of the input with stored info).

temporal-lobe, occipital-lobe, etc.?

I'd say these are definitely warranted, but only with the [tag:neuroanatomy] tag.  So, for example, I don't think every memory question needs a [tag:temporal-lobe] tag if it peripherally relates to the hippocampus.

Uh, I'm not for a separate tag for each lobe. Soon we'll have one for the right hemisphere, one for the left, one for the grey matter, one for the white, one for the amygdala, one for the cerebellum etc. etc. If its about hearing, combining the audition and neuroanatomy tags will be enough differentiation.
